# How prohibit access for some users to special folders?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make my hard drive inaccessible to everyone but me?](https://superuser.com/questions/417055/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-hard-drive-inaccessible-to-everyone-but-me)

I use Windows 8 as Admin  and I also have few other users on my machine. I see that they can't access my folders on the  C: drive, but they can access all folders on my D: drive. Can I select some folders, so they can't access them?

Answer (score 1):

Remove their permissions using the Security tab in the properties of the drive.

[image]

Perhaps check out these related SU questions/answers as well:

- [Vista: setting file permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/312546/vista-setting-file-permissions)
- [Setting permissions on files within subfolders in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/456387/setting-permissions-on-files-within-subfolders-in-windows-7)
- [Equivalent of chmod to change file permissions in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/106181/equivalent-of-chmod-to-change-file-permissions-in-windows)